# Latitude/Longitude Generation to be used as sample data

Tags: csv, maps, simulation, demo

I am writing a demo web application that tracks multiple devices through my companies platform. I have the app working, but need a csv file that will simulate devices moving on a map as if they were a tracker attached to a car. The simulator works by reading 1 row of data every second (1 lat/lng point). Here is an example of the first few lines of a file that would work if the points weren't scattered across the US (the SclId is the device name).

```
SclId   Latitude    Longitude
HAT-0   44.968046   -94.420307
HAT-1   44.33328    -89.132008
HAT-2   33.755787   -116.359998
HAT-3   33.844843   -116.54911
HAT-4   44.92057    -93.44786
HAT-5   44.240309   -91.493619
HAT-0   44.968041   -94.419696
HAT-1   44.333304   -89.132027
HAT-2   33.755783   -116.360066
HAT-3   33.844847   -116.549069
HAT-4   44.920474   -93.447851
HAT-5   44.240304   -91.493768
```

If I had something that could create simulation data with mouse clicks it would save me a lot of time creating another program requiring me to drive around with a device and record the data to a CSV. Any help/recommendations would be greatly appreciated. If you don't understand the question please ask for clarification!

Comment: Thought I'd answer this since it had over 1000 views. I believe what I ended up doing was just console logging the output in a csv format. I then copied and pasted this output into a file and saved it as csv.

Answer (score 3):

There is a website that I use to draw waypoint and download it as any format e.g., GPX, KML, JSON, CSV, etc.

https://www.alltrails.com/explore/map/map-e727fa5--12